# undefined-is-not-an-object-evaluating-this-state-datasource.map

Tags: javascript, react-native

```
componentDidMount(){
    fetch('https://boboboi.online/c_api_sales/get_dest',{
      method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                Accept: 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                        port_code: 'CP-002',
                        api_key: 'ae9a6ce9a7479038d998060ef6d65ca9f86a13ed962a5366b3b0662cc52dde1b',
                        token: 'a959190d43520f8017ed2ca09ffc61bb'
                }),
    })   
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => { 
            this.setState({
                isLoading: false,
                dataSource: responseJson
              }, function() {
                // In this block you can do something with new state.
              });
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              console.error(error);
            });
        }

        GetPickerSelectedItemValue=()=>{

            Alert.alert(this.state.PickerValueHolder);

          }
```

[image: VIEW]
[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome :) Few things to remember, Please never post your code as a screenshot, and secondly please provide full details of your question and what you asking. the way you wrote your question, no will be able to help you - See here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

map() method can be used with array and not with object. So if you want to use map method you can try using it like Object.keys(this.state.dataSource).map((key, index)=> { //your function and logic });

Comment: like what ? do you have an example or recommended site for me to lear ? thankyou

Comment: for your code you can try doing this.

Object.keys(this.state.dataSource).map((key, index) => {

console.log(this.state.dataSource[key]);

});

this will list out all the values from your json object.

checkout this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map